# vagrant+ansibleでWindowsゲスト環境を構築する際の不具合の回避策を教えてください

Tags: macos, windows, vagrant, ansible

ホスト: macOS sierra (Mac mini 2012)
ゲスト: Windows10 Pro x64
仮想環境: Vagrant 1.9.1 (Parallels Desktop 12.1.1 Pro Edition)

**やりたいこと:**

1. Windows仮想開発環境をコマンド一発で構築したい
2. 構成を少しずつ変えながら、何度も頻繁に再構築して動作確認したい

上記のため、Vagrant + Ansible 2.2を使ったWindows環境の構築を試みており、現状Vagrantで最小限のWindows環境が構築完了できています。今後はAnsibleを使って、各種Windowsの環境設定や、Windowsツール類のセットアップなどを全自動でやっていこうと考えています。

そこで、vagrant provisionでansible_localを呼び出したところ、以下のエラーが出て実行できませんでした。

```
`playbook` does not exist on the guest: /vagrant/provision/vagrant.yml
```

これを回避するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

ゲスト側のエクスプローラーで確認したところ、/vagrant/provision/vagrant.ymlの存在は確認でき、メモ帳で開くこともできました。(vagrantによって、ホストから自動的に共有されているようです)
また、vagrant.ymlは現状、動作確認用にHello,worldのようなテキストファイルを吐き出す処理しか書いていません。

どうかご教示いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

**追記**

Vagrantfile は下記のようになっています。

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "windows10-with-devices" # Added usb, sound and net0 (shared)
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3389, host: 3389
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5985, host: 5985, id: "winrm", auto_correct: true
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
  config.vm.graceful_halt_timeout = 600
  config.vm.provider "parallels" do |prl|
    prl.name = "Windows 10"
    prl.linked_clone = true
    prl.update_guest_tools = true
    prl.memory = 6144
    prl.cpus = 4
    prl.customize ["set", :id, "--description", "Vagrant", "--startup-view", "fullscreen", "--longer-battery-life", "off"]
  end
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provision/vagrant.yml"
    ansible.install = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Vagrantの`ansible_local`と言うのは対象マシンにAnsibleを実行するわけ。しかしAnsibleはWindows上で動かない。それは無理です。（cygwinを使って何らか方法がありますが、普通ではありません）。ホストマシンからWindowsのターゲットを管理するしかできません。

Comment: なるほど、今回のケースの場合Ansibleを **macOS側で** 動かして、仮想Windowsを遠隔操作する、と言う形が正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、ホスト側からどうにかする、macOSか、または別の仮想Linux用意するか、そう言う認識ですね。方針が見えてきました。解決策はまだ見えていませんが、一度こちらで調べて試行錯誤してみます。ご教示ありがとうございました！